# Invalid selected value in drop downs : Failed to set selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code which generates drop down list dynamically. 
I am using ng-repeat to generate drop downs dynamically, but i am not getting valid selected values.

I have updated my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y52vm/).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <select ng-model="item.shareToOption" ng-options="c.value for c in shareToOptions"></select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.items = [
    {
    "shareToOption" : {id:1,value:"AA1"}
    },
    {
    "shareToOption" : {id:2,value:"AA2"},
    },
    {
    "shareToOption" : {id:3,value:"AA3"},
    },
    {
    "shareToOption" : {id:4,value:"AA4"}
    }
];

$scope.shareToOptions = [
    {id:1,value:"AA1"},
    {id:2,value:"AA2"},
    {id:3,value:"AA3"},
    {id:4,value:"AA4"}
];
```

**UPDATE**
I don't want to make any change in JSON object, how to achieve result without making any change in JSON object?

Using following code i getting proper id's in model but values are not getting update.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="item.blockName.id" name="blockName" 
              ng-options="choice.id as choice.value for choice in blockNameOptions">

</select>
```

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/LCJub/1/

Change value of first drop down to AA2 but still i am getting model as

```
[{"shareToOption":{"id":2,"value":"AA1"}},{"shareToOption":{"id":2,"value":"AA2"}},{"shareToOption":{"id":3,"value":"AA3"}},{"shareToOption":{"id":4,"value":"AA4"}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` compares by reference, not value.

You need to reference the objects from `$scope.shareToOptions`:

```
$scope.shareToOptions = [
    {id:1,value:"AA1"},
    {id:2,value:"AA2"},
    {id:3,value:"AA3"},
    {id:4,value:"AA4"},
    {id:4,value:"AA5"},
    {id:4,value:"AA6"},
    {id:4,value:"AA7"}
];

$scope.items = [
    {
        "shareToOption" : $scope.shareToOptions[0]
    },
    {
        "shareToOption" : $scope.shareToOptions[1]
    },
    {
        "shareToOption" : $scope.shareToOptions[2]
    },
    {
        "shareToOption" : $scope.shareToOptions[3]
    }
];
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8MU/

If you don't want to change the two existing arrays I would recommend to remap $scope.items at controller initialization to use the correct references:

```
var setReferences = function () {
    var items = $scope.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var reference = $scope.shareToOptions.filter(function (option) {
            return option.id === items[i].shareToOption.id;
        })[0];

        items[i].shareToOption = reference;
    }
};

setReferences();
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/whNzw/

Comment: :I don't want to make any change in JSON object, how to achieve above result without making any change in JSON object?

Comment: Do both arrays need to look exactly like in your example?

Comment: Can you explain, how i can do this?

Comment: :Now i am getting updated id's in model but my values are still old.Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/LCJub/1/

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: :Thanks for guidance.